# Copying a list of test/path/to/files to list of prod/path/to/files

Tags: command-line, cp, xargs

I would like to copy a list of files in the form test/path/to/file/filename.xyz to their corresponding production path prod/path/to/file/filename.xyz. If the test path and the prod path are the same except for the presence of "prod" instead of "test", can I use the following command? Will this overwrite the destination file?

`$ xargs -I % --arg-file=input.txt cp  /test/%  /prod/%`

Comment: why not use rsync? what is the content input.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit input.txt such it reads like (Note the `+`)

```
+ /path/to/file/filename.xyz
```

Then,

```bsh
rsync -amv \
  --include '*/' \
  --include-from input.txt \
  --exclude '*' \
  test/ prod/
```

You can also run it directly with editing the file on the fly, e.g.:

```bsh
rsync -amv \
  --include '*/' \
  --include-from <(sed 's/^/+ /' input.txt) \
  --exclude '*' \
  test/ prod/
```

You might need to change the `sed` expression to fit your needs.